# How to run GraalVM native image with spring cloud bootstrap enabled?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm

I have 3.2.2 spring-boot application with spring cloud bootstrap enabled.
I'm building GraalVm native image with mvn -Pnative native:compile.

When I run the native image I get:

> Web application could not be started as there was no
> org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.server.ReactiveWebServerFactory
> bean defined in the context.

If bootstrap isn't enabled the image works. I also tried adding org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap dependency instead of spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled system property but with the same result.

Does anyone have a solution to get it working even with org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap dependency or spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled property?

**UPDATE**

Minimal dependencies set to reproduce:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: it is working in my machine with [this](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.2.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=bootstrap&name=bootstrap&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.bootstrap&dependencies=cloud-starter,native,webflux). if you share pom and code it may help

Comment: yes it works, but there is no spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap dependency, if you add it to the pom you get the same result as me

Comment: can you share your pom in the question ?

Comment: I added it to the question under UPDATE

Comment: if you check the [link](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.2.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=bootstrap&name=bootstrap&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.bootstrap&dependencies=cloud-starter,native,webflux) I sent which has **spring-cloud-starter** which named as **Cloud Bootstrap** means you should not include spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap as dependency, cloud-starter will be enough.

Comment: we added spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap (or set spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled to true) to enable bootstrap.yml if dependency is not in pom and property is not set to true app won't start in kubernetness

Comment: please check the note at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/blob/main/docs/modules/ROOT/pages/kubernetes-awareness.adoc#breaking-changes-in-30x and then breaking changes, that looks like not supported with SB3 anymore.

Comment: but with the dependency (or the system property) it works fine in k8s, the problem occurs when i try to run the application like native image on docker

Comment: SB3 main change is guaranteeing that graalvm works with dependencies, cloud-starter-bootstrap is not used in SB3 meaning you can have issues with graalvm, and [check](https://github.com/ihuaylupo/manning-smia/issues/14#issuecomment-1009526011) try to merge your bootstrap yml file to application yml and retest, one more pointer https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot2/mergebootstrapyamlwithapplicationyaml

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation, I'll try to discuss the removal of bootstrap with the team

Comment: Yes, the legacy bootstrap is not supported for GraalVM native images.

Answer (score 1):

**spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap** is deprecated and not used in spring boot **3** , you can see it [here](https://github.com/ihuaylupo/manning-smia/issues/14#issuecomment-1009526011)

> Since bootstrap has been deprecated for newer versions of Spring, I think putting it in the application.properties is fine. Check out this StackOverflow (as posted earlier by duydoanx)

Another [doc](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot2/mergebootstrapyamlwithapplicationyaml) shows bootstrap yml is expired. Instead you can use "spring-cloud-starter" and move all bootstrap yml configuration to application yml or properties files,  check [this](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.2.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=bootstrap&name=bootstrap&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.bootstrap&dependencies=cloud-starter,native,webflux) template.

Comment: If I add spring-cloud-starter dependency and move properties from bootstrap.yml to application.yml, application won't start in kubernetes due to unresolved property placeholder

Comment: can you please share a reproducer ? I want to deploy the project in my local and see the error, and I am sure bootstrap dependency and yml is not supported for [graalvm](https://fosstodon.org/@olga_maciaszek/111845520500003098)

Comment: Reproducer of the application with the bootstrap? Now I am trying to remove bootstrap and deploy the application on kubernetes (without graalvm first) but I have a problem with config map, the application won't start because it can't resolve property placeholder. I created a new question for this.

Comment: reproducer without the bootstrap because it is not supported in graalvm anyway. better to fix it without dependeng to bootstrap. if you create a reproducer with that configmap issue I can quickly show how it works and fix.

Comment: I can't make reproducer easily with the deployment and everything. But in short, I thought that if I have spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config dependency and the config map (created from yaml) has the same name as the application (set by spring.application.name property in application.yaml) it should load properties from the config map. In the app I have variable with @Value("${api.portals.basePath}") and the application won't start because it can't resolve it even though it is defined in the config map.

Comment: "api.portals.basePath" was not defined in your yaml in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907757/why-are-properties-from-configmap-not-loaded-even-though-configmap-has-the-same), if you define it under after spring block it should work as expected.

Comment: it is defined in yaml from which the config map is created

Comment: OK, if I define the property in application.yaml as well, it works, so every property I want to have in the config map must also be defined in application.yaml, right? But if I use bootstrap it works with properties defined only in config map. Is there any solution to make it work like with bootstrap but without bootstrap? :D

Comment: I got it, the config map have to be mounted as volume. @ozkanpakdil Thank you for your help and time.